# Firebase "push" creates an "undefined" key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code to add a new Account Type to my firebase db. The problems is that instead of adding a unique key (as it's supposed to) now is adding an "undefined" key, as shown in the picture below

```
addAccountType(item) {
  firebase.database().ref('/houses/').child(this.user.houseid + "/memberaccounttypes/").push({ name: item.name, icon: item.icon });
}
```

[image]

I'm using firebase@^3.4.1

What am I missing?

**UPDATE: NEVER MIND... I MADE SUCH A STUPID MISTAKE**

Instead of calling the `addAccountType(item)` I was calling the `updateAccountType(item)` DUH!!!

Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: Were you able to add the above keys(key that are valid) in `memberaccounttypes` in the same manner as the code that you have shown?

Comment: I've never seen `push()` generate an undefined value. Any chance you can set up a jsbin that reproduces this behavior?